# Facebook app: Choosing an alternate app at install time

Tags: facebook, installation

We (will) have two Facebook apps for our company. Some of our users will be eligible for one, some for the other. This is a disjoint set, no users will be eligible for both apps. What we'd like to do is detect during the login/install process that a user has chosen the wrong app, and redirect them to the correct app

Is this possible within the Facebook framework?

Answer (score 1):

No, this functionality does not exist within the Facebook framework. You will have to use your own custom script to decide which app to direct them to.

Answer (score 0):

> Some of our users will be eligible for one, some for the other. This is a disjoint set, no users will be eligible for both apps.

Define “eligible” in this context, please.

> What we'd like to do is detect during the login/install process that a user has chosen the wrong app, and redirect them to the correct app

And define what you would want to base that decision on at that point too, please.

---

Apart from the unclear question, *one* app could still do different things for different users, and could make the decision to categorize which user how based on all the data available to that app.

Comment: Our company produces two different products that we are exposing through Facebook. These are existing products. They are different some people pay for app A, some for app B. Their user ID (used during signup) is what will define which Facebook app they should have access to. One is currently running on Facebook (IDX Pro), we're adding the second. They have completely different URLs, so the Canvas page setup is different for each. Does that make more sense?

Comment: A little more clarification (I hope): 

When they install the App on their FB page, they are asked for their userID. We currently look at the userID, and determine whether they have purchased our "program" - the one that is enabled for that FB app. The current FB app says that they have entered an invalid userID. Now that we are "enabling" both our programs for FaceBook, we'd like to look at the userID, and say "No, you really want to install **this** facebook app instead.